# Use an existing property in assigning a value to a new Member

Tags: javascript

Pardon my title guys. I tried thinking hard but couldn't think of better title. My question is simple how can I do something like following in javascript.

```
var blah={ try2:[45,56],try1:try2[0]};
console.log(blah);
```

Comment: What do you expect for the output of `console.log(blah);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in an object literal.  You'd have to do:

```
var blah = { try2: [45, 46] };
blah.try1 = blah.try2[0];
```

When you really want to be able to express that as a single expression, you can use an anonymous function:

```
var blah = (function() {
  var obj = { try2: [45, 46] };
  obj.try1 = obj.try2[0];
  return obj;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation:

```
var blah = { try2: arr, try1: arr[0] };
```

(where `arr` refers to your array object, `[45, 56]` in your case).

Since, the array is needed for two properties of the object literal, it makes more sense to pull the array definition outside of the object literal, and then to use an identifier (like `arr`) to refer to the array... This pattern is cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would avoid using try# as an identifier. try is a resevered word in javascript (and many other languages)

I would do it as follows

```
var blah= { try0:[45,56] } 
blah['try1'] = blah.try0
console.log(blah)
```

you could also do it

```
var blah= { try0:[45,56] } 
blah.try1 = blah.try0
console.log(blah)
```

the result would be as follows

```
    Object
     try0: Array[2]
     try1: Array[2]
     __proto__: Object
```

as you can observe: http://jsfiddle.net/CCf2e/

but, simply, you can not refer to an object while its being initialized in that fashion. try0 cannot be called because it doesn't exist yet.